# How to get this layout using tailwind and map elements

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, tailwind-css

I am trying to get this layout using tailwind css and also render elements in this order with vue or react

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This layout is called "masonry". I recommend that you check how to do that one in CSS (or with some vanilla JS/package), it's not specific to React nor Vue per-se.

As of how to implement it exactly, SO is not a coding platform so I recommend that you Google that for further progress.

Comment: Thanks, I just need it to use "columns-3" with tailwind.

Comment: @dante column will not keep the 1, 2, 3 order actually. More of a 1, 4, 2, 3 5, 3, 6 as in your example.

Comment: yeah I realized that.